# Get the data from the "Version" Tab in Dll properties with c# code?

Tags: assemblies, assemblyfileversion

I want to get the FileVersion (or ProductVersion) and the Comments fields which are in the "Version" tab of a dll using a c# code.

I tried to use the Assembly class, but didn't find the data I need.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Assembly only knows the AssemblyVersion.  To get File information, you need to look at the file properties using [FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx).